# Sum over N days in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below table

| AccountID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 07/06/2021 | 2000 |
| 123 | 07/12/2021 | 9000 |
| 123 | 07/16/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/20/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/28/2021 | 500 |

I am trying to sum the amount over 5 working days and get the output like below

| AccountID | Date | Sum Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 07/06/2021 | 11000 |
| 123 | 07/12/2021 | 9500 |
| 123 | 07/16/2021 | 1000 |
| 123 | 07/20/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/28/2021 | 500 |

Also I am trying to ignore weekends(Saturday and Sunday)

I was able to add over 5 days using the below query. But not able to skip weekends.

```
Select distinct
t1.accountid,
convert(datetime,t1.[date]),
t1.amount,
sum(t2.amount)
from [dbo].[HANMI_ABRIGO_TRANSACTIONS] t1
cross apply 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[HANMI_ABRIGO_TRANSACTIONS] a
    WHERE a.accountid= t1.accountid 
    AND 
        (
        convert(datetime,a.[date]) < DATEADD(DAY,5,convert(datetime,t1.[date])) 
        AND
        convert(datetime,a.[date]) >= convert(datetime,t1.[date])
        ) 
    And a.accountid = '123'
    And a.date like '2021-07%'
    and a.amount > 0
)t2
where t1.accountid = '123'
And t1.date like '2021-07%'
and t1.amount > 0
group by 
t1.accountid,
convert(datetime,t1.[date]),
t1.amount
order by convert(datetime,t1.[date])
```

Thanks!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: If your problem is to skip weekend you can filter DATEPART(weekday, Date). The output is a number between 1 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the query you are asking for:

```
SELECT AccountId, Date,
(
  SELECT SUM(Amount) 
  FROM HANMI_ABRIGO_TRANSACTIONS h2
  WHERE 
    h1.AccountID = h2.AccountID and 
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7) and
    h2.Date between h1.Date AND DATEADD(d, 5, h1.Date)
) as SumAmount
FROM HANMI_ABRIGO_TRANSACTIONS h1
```

The results are:

| AccountId | Date | SumAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-07-06 | 2000 |
| 123 | 2021-07-12 | 9500 |
| 123 | 2021-07-16 | 1000 |
| 123 | 2021-07-20 | 500 |
| 123 | 2021-07-28 | 500 |

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d6bae/8

Comment: Thanks. The script seems to skip only Sunday since 2021/07/06 is a Tuesday so if we skip both Saturday and Sunday( 2021/07/10 and 2021/07/11) the sum for 2021/07/06 should be 11000.

Comment: @rohitpandey Then, can you update your expected results in your question, please? I mean the results of my query match the expected results in your question.

Comment: @rohitpandey maybe your system language settings do not take Sunday as 1. So, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7)  is not correct for you, but DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (6, 7). You can take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Looks the date difference where we check whether dates falls within 5 days or not we have use 6 instead of 5 ‘DATEADD(d, 6, h1.Date’. This gave me expected output and I tested on some more scenarios. Not able to understand reason behind this that when we are adding 6 days then why system checks for only 5 after excluding Saturday and Sunday. But works.Thanks!

Comment: If it works fine, please, don't forget to mark it as accepted answer ;) thank you